# Struts <bean:cookie> tag breaks on WebLogic 11gR1

Tags: java, cookies, struts, weblogic, classloader

I'm trying to deploy a very simple **Struts** app on **WebLogic 11gR1**. The app has one JSP called Welcome.jsp and this JSP contains the following tag :

```
<bean:cookie name="" id=""/>
```

The associated taglib is imported at the top of the JSP using the following line :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```

When this tag is inside the JSP, I've the following error :

```
Welcome.jsp:11:24: javax.servlet.http.Cookie cannot be resolved
<body bgcolor="white"><bean:cookie name="" id=""/>
```

But when I remove this tag, the Welcome.jsp works just fine.

The JSP includes other tags like :

```
<bean:message key="welcome.heading"/>
```

Those tags are working just fine.

And to finish, the `ActionServlet` of **Struts** is also working and starting with the app.

I'm guessing that there must be a classloading problem but I don't understand why the **Struts** `ActionServlet` is working : `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` and `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` are declared in the same package.

Maybe, there is a problem with the Oracle implementation of the `Cookie` class in WebLogic but it is very unlikely.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions at all? If so, can you provide it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.servlet.http.Cookie` is an interface showing the structure that those who are implementing the Servlet API need to implement.

The issue might be with your WebLogic 11gR1 configuration/libary: I'll explain using Tomcat 7.0.

In Tomcat 7.0, under `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder, there's a `servlet-api.jar`. That jar allows Tomcat to support the Java Servlet API specification (and has Cookie.class included in the directory, under javax/servlet/Cookie).

Your WebLogic 11gR1 must have a Servlet Container library that conforms to the Servlet API (like Tomcat's servlet-api.jar). I never used WebLogic, but if you have a lib folder somewhere (apparently `WL_HOME/server/lib`), make sure there's a servlet api somewhere (I think weblogic.jar contains servlet api implementations).

Also, please check that you don't have a servlet like library (e.g. servlet-api.jar, eclipse servlet jars, etc.) inside your WAR file as it can conflict with WebLogic's servlet library.

Comment: I've checked that I don't have a servlet library inside my WAR (Maven scope : provided). As I said in the question, WebLogic provide a servlet librairy with javax.servlet.http.Cookie and javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet, but it doesn't work as expected.